# Selecting a row out of a group with conditions?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset of rows of genes with genes also in groups. I am looking to select 1 gene per group into a new dataframe based on a few conditions:

1. Select the gene with the highest score if the score difference between others in the group is >0.02
2. If the score difference between genes in a group is <0.02 then select a gene with a higher `direct_count`
3. If the direct_count is the same select the gene with the highest `secondary_count`
4. If everything is the same select both genes.

I've been trying to use similar questions on here, but I'm having trouble making other examples work for my code with setting up this many conditions.

The data I have looks like:

```
  Group Gene      Score     direct_count   secondary_count 
    1   AQP11    0.5566507       4               5
    1   CLNS1A   0.2811747       0               2
    1   RSF1     0.5469924       3               6
    2   CFDP1    0.4186066       1               2
    2   CHST6    0.4295135       1               3
    3   ACE      0.634           1               1
    3   NOS2     0.6345          1               1
    4   Gene1    0.1            10               20
    4   Gene2    0.68            3                1
    4   Gene3    0.7             0                1
```

Output selection of gene per group:

```
 Group Gene      Score     direct_count   secondary_count 
    1   AQP11    0.5566507       4               5       #highest direct_count
    2   CHST6    0.4295135       1               3       #highest secondary_count after matching direct_count
    3   ACE      0.634           1               1       #ACE and NOS2 have matching counts
    3   NOS2     0.6345          1               1
```

I am trying to use `dplyr::group_by()` with if statements currently.

Input data:

```
structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), Gene = c("AQP11", 
"CLNS1A", "RSF1", "CFDP1", "CHST6", "ACE", "NOS2", "Gene1", "Gene2", "Gene3"), Score = c(0.5566507, 
0.2811747, 0.5269924, 0.4186066, 0.4295135, 0.634, 0.6345, 0.1, 0.68, 0.7), direct_count = c(4L, 
0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 10L, 3L, 0L ), secondary_count = c(5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 20L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

Edit:
Including sessioninfo and also want to note in my real data some rows have NA for their `direct_count` and `secondary_count`.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18362)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] forcats_0.5.0     stringr_1.4.0     purrr_0.3.4       readr_1.4.0      
 [5] tibble_3.0.4      ggplot2_3.3.2     tidyverse_1.3.0   tidyr_1.1.2      
 [9] dplyr_1.0.2       data.table_1.13.2

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.5       cellranger_1.1.0 pillar_1.4.6     compiler_4.0.2  
 [5] dbplyr_1.4.4     tools_4.0.2      jsonlite_1.7.1   lubridate_1.7.9 
 [9] lifecycle_0.2.0  gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_0.4.8     
[13] reprex_0.3.0     cli_2.1.0        DBI_1.1.0        rstudioapi_0.11 
[17] haven_2.3.1      withr_2.3.0      xml2_1.3.2       httr_1.4.2      
[21] fs_1.5.0         generics_0.0.2   vctrs_0.3.4      gtools_3.8.2    
[25] hms_0.5.3        grid_4.0.2       tidyselect_1.1.0 glue_1.4.1      
[29] R6_2.4.1         fansi_0.4.1      readxl_1.3.1     modelr_0.1.8    
[33] blob_1.2.1       magrittr_1.5     backports_1.1.10 scales_1.1.1    
[37] ellipsis_0.3.1   rvest_0.3.6      assertthat_0.2.1 colorspace_1.4-1
[41] stringi_1.5.3    munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.2      crayon_1.3.4
```

Edit problem with selection for real data:

```
structure(list(Group = c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Gene = c("CFDP1", 
"CHST6", "RNU6-758P", "Gene1", "TMEM170A"), Score = c(0.551740109920502, 
0.598918557167053, 0.564491391181946, 0.567291617393494, 0.616708278656006
), direct_count = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0), secondary_count = c(62, 
6, 1, 1, 2)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000183dc6b1ef0>)
```

from this group `Gene1` is being selected when it should actually be `CHST6` and I can't find why.

Data looks like:

```
    
   Group Gene         Score      direct_count      secondary_count
1   2    CFDP1        0.5517401        1                  62
2   2    CHST6        0.5989186        1                   6
3   2    RNU6-758P    0.5644914        0                   1
4   2    Gene1        0.5672916        0                   1
5   2    TMEM170A     0.6167083        0                   2
```

CHST6 has the highest `direct_count` out of all genes <0.05 of the to the top scored gene in this group, yet Gene1 is being selected.

Comment: Your dataset is a `data.table`.  I guess a data.table option would be efficient

Comment: all I think. And thank you I will look into data.table

Answer (score 1):

Your data:

```
> db
# A tibble: 7 x 5
  Group `p Gene` Score direct_count secondary_count
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1 AQP11    0.557            4               5
2     1 CLNS1A   0.281            0               2
3     1 RSF1     0.547            3               6
4     2 CFDP1    0.419            1               2
5     2 CHST6    0.430            1               3
6     3 ACE      0.634            1               1
7     3 NOS2     0.634            1               1
```

Now we first write a function such that for a df with only one group it does what want:

```
gene_selection = function (df) {
  if (dim(df)[1]==1) {
    return(df)
  }
  else {
    df=arrange(df,-Score)
    if((df$Score[1]-df$Score[2])>0.2) {
      return(df[1,])
    }
    else{
      if (df$direct_count[1]!=df$direct_count[2]) {
        return(df[which.max(df$direct_count[1:2]),])
      }
      else {
        if (df$secondary_count[1]!=df$secondary_count[2]) {
          return(df[which.max(df$secondary_count[1:2]),])
        }
        else {
          return(df[1:2,])
        }
      }
    }
  }  
}
```

Now using `group_map` to implement this function on all groups:

```
> db%>%
+     mutate(Group2=Group) %>%
+     group_by(Group2) %>%
+     group_map(~gene_selection(.)) %>%
+     bind_rows()
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  Group `p Gene` Score direct_count secondary_count
  <dbl> <chr>    <dbl>        <dbl>           <dbl>
1     1 AQP11    0.557            4               5
2     2 CHST6    0.430            1               3
3     3 NOS2     0.634            1               1
4     3 ACE      0.634            1               1
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It gives an error: ```Error in if ((df$Score[1] - df$Score[2]) > 0.2) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed``` - is this a problem with my data? My actual data has many rows and groups, with 18 columns in total.

Comment: More rows and columns shouldn't be a problem. Is there a group for which there maybe only one Gene?

Comment: Ah yes some groups only have 1 gene

Comment: I have edited the function to account for this. Hope it works fine now.

Comment: Thank you, I am now getting an error on the second section of code, that is: ```Error in mutate(Group2 = Group) : object 'Group' not found``` I'm not sure why as ```Group``` is the correct column name

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Please recheck if the name is group instead of Group.

Comment: Also please confirm whether the first condition requires the difference between max and min within a group to be more than 0.02 or between any of the two within that group? My answer is based on the latter but I see an answer based on the former also.

Comment: Yes I am looking for the conditions as you do them, not between any 2 but the highest scored gene should be selected if it's >0.5 in comparison to all other genes in the group. I just found I needed to remove the ```+``` to resolve my error, so this all runs now, thank you

Comment: Great! Sorry I should have posted the code without '+' to avoid confusion. About the condition: you may want to edit your question to update to conditions. Also what do you mean when you say it should be >0.5 *in comparison to all other genes*?

Comment: Sorry, just a typo, I've been trying other thresholds than the 0.02. You've given me the exact results I was expecting in my real data and I will give the bounty when I can.

Answer (score 1):

`group_by` and `filter` from the tidyverse are your friends here.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df <- structure(list(Group = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), 
Gene = c("AQP11", "CLNS1A", "RSF1", "CFDP1", "CHST6", "ACE", "NOS2"), Score = c(0.5566507,0.2811747, 0.5269924, 0.4186066, 0.4295135, 0.634, 0.6345), direct_count = c(4L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), secondary_count = c(5L, 2L, 6L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -7L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
                 
                 
new_df <- df %>%
  #first condition
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(max_score_difference = abs(max(Score)-min(Score))) %>%
  filter((max_score_difference > 0.02 & Score == max(Score)) | max_score_difference < 0.02) %>%
  # second condition
  filter(max_score_difference > 0.02 | (max_score_difference < 0.02 & direct_count == max(direct_count))) %>%
  # third condition
  filter(max_score_difference > 0.02 | (max_score_difference < 0.02 & secondary_count == max(secondary_count))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  #fourth condition met by max statements in filters above
  select(-max_score_difference) %>%
  data.frame()

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Thank you for this,  is this affect by rows with NA? Running it on my real data and it removes from groups entirely from the selection, looks like ones where some genes in groups have ```direct_count``` as NA

Comment: In this case, I think it would work fine if you add the ```na.rm=TRUE``` argument to the max statements. I.E. ```max(direct_count, na.rm=TRUE)``` This will make sure the filtering is not messed up by looking for a max among a sample that includes NA values. Alternatively, you could make NA's into 0s, if that was appropriate for your count data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach although it would be nicer to have a larger dataset to verify this works.

```r
library(data.table)

dt[,
   {
     if (.N == 1L) 
       ind = 1L
     else {
      o = sort(Score, decreasing = TRUE, index.return = TRUE)
      x = o$x
      ix = o$ix
      if (x[1L] - x[2L] > 0.05) 
        ind = ix[1L]
      else {
        search_inds = ix[which(x[1L] - x <= 0.05)]
        direct_count_sub = direct_count[search_inds]
        wm_dc = which.max(direct_count_sub)
        
        if (sum((dc_max <- direct_count_sub[wm_dc] == direct_count_sub)) == 1L)
          ind = search_inds[wm_dc]
        else {
          secondary_count_sub = secondary_count[search_inds]
          wm_sc = which.max(secondary_count_sub)
          if (sum((sc_max <- secondary_count_sub[wm_sc] == secondary_count_sub)) == 1L)
            ind = search_inds[wm_sc]
          else
            ind = search_inds[dc_max & sc_max]
        }
      }
     }
     .SD[ind]
   },
   by = Group]

##   Group   Gene     Score direct_count secondary_count
##   <int> <char>     <num>        <int>           <int>
##1:     1  AQP11 0.5566507            4               5
##2:     2  CHST6 0.4295135            1               3
##3:     3    ACE 0.6340000            1               1
##4:     3   NOS2 0.6345000            1               1
```

Note, [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) is very influenced by base. We are largely going through your 4 criteria by group and then subsetting the group based on which case was true.

Comment: Thank you for this. Is there a way to set the <0.02 filter (after selecting genes per group that are >0.02) so it only then takes genes into the next set of conditions if they are in <0.02 distance with the top scored gene per group? So not any gene that is <0.02 with any other gene in the group.

Comment: I'll look into it after work. Could you update your example data with a case of this? But I think I understand

Comment: Thank you for this I really appreciate it! I have added the example that is causing me to question this at the very end of my question (also changed my threshold from 0.02 to 0.05).

Comment: I just saw you had another bounty for a similar question. Did this answer overlook something?